# Finding $\sqrt{625}$ without a calculator

Tags: calculus, roots

We were factoring $25n^2+15n-4$ in class and my professor used the quadratic formula. This root came up and he wrote the answer directly. He doesn't want us to use calculators.

Is there any trick for this?

Comment: Observe $\sqrt{625} = \sqrt{25 \cdot 25}$.

Comment: You can guesstimate pretty easily: it's larger than $20$ (since $20^2=400$), and smaller than $30$ ($30^2=900$). Next thing to try, given that it ends in $25$, is $25$, and voila!

Comment: It's experience and memorization.  All the comments that say "observe" or "remark" are people who also have experience and recognize numbers that factor into many small integers. It's not a bad skill to have, especially considering that your prof doesn't want you to use calculators.

Comment: Clearly $25\,|\,625$, just take the quotient.  You can do that mentally.  How many quarters are in $\$6.25$?

Comment: Well, the trick is to facto $625$ and remove any perfect squares. Obviously $5|625$ and we get $625=5*125$.  And $5|125$ and we get $125=5*25$ and .... that's really it, isn't it.... $625=5*125 = 5*5*25= 5^2*5^2=5^4$ and $\sqrt{5^4} = 5^2=25$.   A harder example might be $\sqrt {108}$.  $108 = 2*54=2^2*27=2^2*3*9=2^2*3^3$ and the squares we can factor out are $108= (2^2*3^2)*3=6^2*3$ so $\sqrt{108}=\sqrt{6^2*3}= 6\sqrt 3$.

Comment: @fleablood That's waaaay too much trouble without a calculator, imo

Comment: Get used to it.  You will get *no* sympathy for complaining about  $\sqrt{625}=5\sqrt{\frac {625}{25}}=5\sqrt{\frac{6*100+25}{25}}=5\sqrt{6*4+1}=5*\sqrt{25}=5*5=25$ is "unreasonable" to figure out on one's own.  It may not seem obvious at first but you will be expected to find these ideas reasonable and to catch on to them very fast.  In fact, you will be expected to find these ideas to be cool and fun.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Remark that $625=5^4$, and take the square root..

Comment: How am I supposed to know that?

Comment: It is clear that the number is divisible by $5$..

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire  You can factor the number into primes.  Since the units digit is $5$, $625$ must be divisible by $5$.  Dividing by $5$ yields $625 = 5 \cdot 125$.  Now factor $125$ into primes.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig So much work when I could just use a calculator and will realistically do so when I get a job in this field...

Comment: You're supposed to know that having made computations  by hand at school a sufficient number of times.

Comment: "and will realistically do so when I get a job in this field."  I'd never hire you if I saw you reach for a calculator when asked this.  In practice; numbers that end in $00,25,50,75$ are always divisible by $25$ which is a square. This is such a *common* calculation and for such a simple reason ($25$ divides $100$ so $25$ divides $100a + 25m$) I'd expect most people be able to do it in their sleep.  (Once they learn it, that is.  The first $3$ times it's not obvious, but the fourth....)

Answer (score 2):

$20^2=400<625<900=30^2$, so $625=(2 \_)^2$. The only integer $x$ between $0$ and $9$ such that $x^2$ ends with $5$ is $5$, so if we try $25$, we come with $(25)^2=625$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your professor has been using the following trick: the square of a number of the form $10n + 5$ is $100n(n+1) + 25$. Indeed $(10n + 5)^2 = 100n^2 + 100n + 25 = 100n(n+1) + 25$.
For instance:
\begin{align}
n &= 0: && 5^2 = 25 &&\text{since $0 \times 1 = 0$} \\
n &= 1: && 15^2 = 225 &&\text{since $1 \times 2 = 2$} \\
n &= 2: && 25^2 = 625 &&\text{since $2 \times 3 = 6$} \\
n &= 3: && 35^2 = 1225 &&\text{since $3 \times 4 = 12$} \\
n &= 4: && 45^2 = 2025 &&\text{since $4 \times 5 = 20$} \\
n &= 5: && 55^2 = 3025 &&\text{since $5 \times 6 = 30$} \\
&\ \vdots
\end{align}
If you know this trick, it is not difficult to remember that $25^2 = 625$...

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
Decompose 625 into prime factors to see how you can find $\sqrt{625}$ without a calculator.

Prime factorization helps makes calculations nicer if you extract the square from the square root. For example, $\sqrt{8} = \sqrt{2^3} = 2\sqrt{2}$. Most of the people find $2\sqrt{2}$ much nicer to work with than $\sqrt{8}$.